Which List implementation does Kotlin use when calling listOf()
As known, in Java List is not a class, but an interface, so you can't get an instance of a List, you have to specify the implementation, like ArrayList, LinkedList, etc. So here is the question: which List implementation does Kotlin use, when creating one with listOf() or mutableListOf().

Just inspect it with println(listOf(...)::class). This is implementation detail and will likely change in the future.

If you check the documentation you will see it links directly to the source code.

@dominicoder can you decipher the class from that? It looks to be using a varargs which is an array which then uses "asList"

Not only can it change in the future, but it already uses more than one different implementation depending on which overload of the function you call.

@matt you can decipher it if you follow the same steps to consult the docs for asList and view the source code.

@dominicoder I tried, I don't use kotlin so I'm not so well versed in it. It's just not as easy as you make it seem to be. There are a fews unclear steps from where you linked it. My comment was actually a challenge to you, can you find where in the source it actually says what List implementation is being used?

@matt don't have space to add all the links but: asList is documented with links to the source code. Assuming you want the generic version for Java, per the question, the source for that as linked shows that it uses ArraysUtilJVM. Searching GitHub for that class shows that it's just Arrays.asList which in turn is just new ArrayList source

The exact implementation of listOf() has not been exposed and It is not mentioned directly in the official documentation.
It doesn't return a specific implementation(In contrast to the specification that mutableListOf() returns an ArrayList). listOf() focuses on performance and returns an efficient implementation. That's why it is Immutable.
The official documentation mentions that MutableList can be considered a resizable array in Kotlin. Therefore, I think we can consider listOf() as returning an optimized array. You can refer to the item about List in the Kotlin collections documentation.

Unknown, and irrelevant.
The documentation promises only that you get a read-only List. The programmers implementing that method are free to use any class they want as long as it meets the requirements of a read-only List. Their choice of class may vary between versions of their implementation. Their choice of class may even vary at runtime, choosing among various classes depending on the particular situation.
If you value certain behaviors of a certain List implementation, then use that specific implementation rather than listOf. You cannot expect anything more of listOf than is promised by its documentation.
To satisfy curiosity, call the override of Object#getClass. Or look at the source code for an implementation. The implementation at the OpenJDK project is open source. But beware: other versions, and other implementations , may vary.

I see. I am just curious about how Kotlin compiler decides which implementation to use.

@AndreyVoeyko The best way to know how something is implemented is to look at the source code. As mentioned by dominicoder's comment, the standard library's documentation has links to the GitHub repo. Another way to is use your IDE to navigate to the implementations (e.g., via ctrl+click) or use the debugger. Just note that the implementation may change between versions; in real code, always write your code based on the API, not the implementation.

public actual fun  listOf(element: T): List = java.util.Collections.singletonList(element)
